# How to update Thingsboard dashboard state without having to click on a row

Tags: state, dashboard, thingsboard

On my thingsboard dashboard, the card and time series widget only displays a value when I click on a row of the entities table widget on the dashboard, thereby populating the dashboard state, I want to be able to automatically update the dashboard state with an entity value as default value before any row is clicked which would in turn display on my time series and card widget on the dashboard.

I have tried using the self.ctx.stateController.updateState('default', currentStateParams, false). I really don't know what currentStateParams to pass in for this method and if at all it is what will update the state, also am I to add it to the onInit function of the entities table widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the widgetContext.updateAliases()

Take this example,

```
function ($event, widgetContext, entityId, entityName, htmlTemplate, additionalParams, entityLabel) { 
let $injector = widgetContext.$scope.$injector;
let assetService = $injector.get(widgetContext.servicesMap.get('assetService'));


function save() {
    let asset = {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'type',
        label: 'label'
    };
    assetService.saveAsset(asset).subscribe(
        function (asset) {
            saveAttributes(asset.id).subscribe(
                function () {
                    widgetContext.updateAliases();
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
    
function saveAttributes(entityId) {}
```

}

Context: I'm calling the updateAliases function inside a widget custom action,
[image]